# Install driver in android os

Tags: android-x86

I recently bought a wifi adapter(Astrum NA150) which is not supported by linux out-of-the-box. But in the cd there are drivers for win,mac,linux and android. They also have makefile. But as i know make is not supported by android.How can i install them.

Link to the drivers:
http://astrumworld.com/Downloads/drivers/NA150_driver.zip

Comment: This is about Ethernet detection. But I am trying to install driver.

Comment: See the second point in my answer: kernel configuration. There's no concept of Windows-like driver installation on Linux, and hence Android.

Comment: Ok. I am just a novice programer. Can you link me to a detailed guide on kernel building and driver. (Beginer friendly)

Comment: Seeing all that codes making me dizzy!!!

Comment: [Kernel building](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+kernel+compilation+guide) is the smaller problem. The bigger one is the availability of kernel source code for your Android device. Deal with that first. // Btw, development related questions are off-topic here.

Comment: It's android x86 on pc.

Comment: Shouldn't code be universal for pc.

Comment: I want to add drivers to phoenix os or prime os